# What is wrong in regexp in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the word text2, but it returns null. Could you please correct it ?

```
String str = "Text SETVAR((&&text1 '&&text2'))";
Pattern patter1 = Pattern.compile("SETVAR\\w+&&(\\w+)'\\)\\)");
Matcher matcher = patter1.matcher(str);
String result = null;
if (matcher.find()) {
    result = matcher.group(1);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: What are you trying to match from `str`? please post a clear example of the desired output.

Comment: If you want to solve a problem with regex then you have two problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't match your string, because you didn't specify the opened parenthesis also `\\w+` will match any combinations of word character and it won't match space and `&`.

Instead you can use a negated character class `[^']+` which will match any combinations of characters with length 1 or more except one quotation :

```
String str = "Text SETVAR((&&text1 '&&text2'))";

"SETVAR\\(\\([^']+'&&(\\w+)'\\)\\)"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7OWjQ-4rT3wIbHLc)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to match all possible pattern in parentheses:

```
String str = "Text SETVAR((&&text1 '&&text2'))";
Pattern patter1 = Pattern.compile("SETVAR[(]{2}&&\\w+\\s*'&&(\\w+)'[)]{2}");
Matcher matcher = patter1.matcher(str);
String result = "";
if (matcher.find()) {
    result = matcher.group(1);
}
System.out.println(result);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/hRe0qw)

You can also use `[^()]*` inside the parentheses to just get to the value inside single apostrophes:

```
Pattern patter1 = Pattern.compile("SETVAR[(]{2}[^()]*'&&(\\w+)'[)]{2}");
                                               ^^^^^^
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/Nlh3hT)

Let me break down the regex for you:

- `SETVAR` - match `SETVAR` literally, then...
- `[(]{2}` - match 2 `(` literally, then...
- `[^()]*` - match 0 or more characters other than `(` or `)` up to...
- `'&&` - match a single apostrophe and two `&` symbols, then...
- `(\\w+)` - match and capture into Group 1 one or more word characters
- `'[)]{2}` - match a single apostrophe and then 2 `)` symbols literally.

Comment: Usually, the correct answer that was provided first and worked for you is marked as accepted, but it is certainly up to you to choose. Best regards and happy weekend.